# How can I do horizontal scrolling animations?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, scroll, ui-design

Some websites have some elements that slide horizontally while you are scroll(vertically). Have an example about it in http://www.timeslot.com/. How can I do that with javascript and css? Or do you have any codepen etc. instance about it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website probably works with different kind of techniques, for example, playing certain animations on scroll. I can recommend "gsap scrolltriger" or "locomotive-scroll", which has an effect to scroll horizontally. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess you just answered a bunch of questions I might ask! It helps a lot!

Comment: Sure, no problem